# How to get the indices of reversed duplicates in a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
list1 =[('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f'),('g','h'),('b','a'),('e','d'),('e','g'),('h','g')]
```

I wish to append the indices of reversed duplicates from this list. For example:

```
('a','b') == ('b','a')
('g','h') == ('h','g')
```

I tried

```
exec =[]
for i,x in enumerate(list1):
    z=x[::-1]
    if z in list1:
        exec.append(i)
        list1.remove(z)
```

I got:

```
exec
[0, 3]
```

Which is correct. However, this is very inefficient when running on a 10 million elements of list. I know that I can directly remove the reversed duplicates by:

```
data = list({tuple(sorted(item)) for item in list1})
```

But I only want to identify the indices of reversed duplicates here. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't modify a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: This actually has a bug, as pointed out, because you are doing `list1.remove(z)` as you iterate over it

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Do you ultimately want to remove the duplicates or do you specifically want to id the duplicates unrelated to removing them?

Comment: @Iwishworldpeace should `[('a','b'), ('a','b')]` return an empty list or `[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuples as a key of a dictionary, so create a dictionary where the sorted tuples are keys and the values are the first index where that tuple occurs in your list. Then, when you encounter a tuple that's already in the dictionary, you can add the index to your output list:

```
indices_dict = {}
dup_indices = []

for index, item in enumerate(list1):
    s_item = tuple(sorted(item))
    if s_item in indices_dict:
        dup_indices.append(indices_dict[s_item])
    else:
        indices_dict[s_item] = index
```

Which gives

```
dup_indices = [0, 3]
```

If you only care about *reversed* duplicates, i.e. if `[('a','b'), ('a','b')]` should return an empty list, change `s_item = tuple(sorted(item))` to `s_item = item[::-1]` like you already have in your code.

Comment: it's supposed to be reversed, not sorted IIUC

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `sorted()` converts e.g. `('b', 'a')` to `('a', 'b')` so that both their indices go to the same list. `reversed()` would create two keys.

Comment: yes, but I assume the OP wants *only* reversed dupilcates, So a simple example, `[('a','b'), ('a','b')]` should return an empty list

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I wish to get only the indices of the reversed duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Turn the list into a set, to make membership testing efficient.

Don't remove from a list while you're iterating over it, so append the elements you're keeping to a new list.

```
execlist = []
set1 = set(list1)
newlist1 = []
for i, x in enumerate(list1):
    if x[::-1] in set1:
        execlist.append(i)
    else:
        newlist1.append(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, I felt something was fishy about it, but couldn't remember.

Comment: This is really helpful, Barmar. Even though newlist1 is not needed, it is a nice way to avoid removing elements from a list while getting the indices that I want. Thank you!